# PhpStorm xdebug breakpoints not functioning correctly

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm having a difficult time getting certain breakpoints to work within my project.  Here is the directory structure for my project:

```
/repo (git root)
  /Portal
    /store
      /classes
        /mvc
          /store
            /actions
              MyAction.php
    /templates
      /store1
        /actions
          MyChildAction.php (child of MyAction)
        index.php
```

Now, if I set a breakpoint in the index.php within "/store1" it works just fine.  If I set a breakpoint within MyChildAction.php it works fine.  However, if I set a breakpoint in MyAction within the "mvc" directory it is completely ignored.  If I use xdebug_break() inside of MyAction.php it does in fact work, which is confusing me.  I haven't set any path maps due to the fact that the file structure and the remote structure are exactly the same.

Here is the xdebug log for the breakpoint that should be hit:

> <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f
>   file:///Users/userName/Workspace/repo/Portal/store/classes/mvc/store/actions/MyAction.php
>   -n 24
>   ->

(I've renamed a lot of the directories, so please excuse the redundant naming conventions)

NOTE: It seems to be something with the PSR 4 autoloading.  I define the vendor/autoload in index.php within the /templates/store1 directory.

Comment: Possibly missing path mappings -- especially if symbolic links are used (remember -- xdebug works with real/resolved paths ONLY). Another possible reason -- wrong casing. If you rename "mvc" to Mvc" (for example), you will see new name in Finder .. but in terminal old casing may still be used (I've seen 3 or 4 cases like that in the past).

Comment: It seems to result from autoloaded classes.  If I add the require_once "/path/to/MyAction.php" it works.  It seems xdebug does not respect the require_once "vendors/autoload.php" composer autoload file.

Comment: *" It seems xdebug does not respect the require_once "vendors/autoload.php" composer autoload file"* I REALLY doubt about it. Always worked fine for me (Linux & Windows -- have no Mac to run/test there). autoload is either works (class is loaded and PHP knows about it) or not (and PHP does not know about it). There was onw ticket -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23944#comment=27-766158 where path separators used in custom autoloader had something to do with similar behavior .. but you are using managed by composer autoloader ... where this should not happen.

Comment: I should have updated this question, my apologies.  I actually found out what was happening, and you would be correct.  I checked the result of get_included_files() (from a manual breakpoint) and noticed the files I expected for xdebug to resolve to were not in that collection.  Needless to say the issue was my PSR-4 autoload configuration; adjusting that fixed the problem.  Thanks.